# Getting error extracting image 'src' using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm having difficulty extracting an image src using Python 2.7, beautifulsoup4 (4.2.1).

The [HTML](http://www.latimes.com/business/la-fi-tn-buzzfeed-deal-20140811-story.html) section I am interested in is:

```
<div class="trb_embed_media ">  <figure imgratio="16x9" imgwidth="750" imgheight="450" data-role="imgsize_item" class="trb_embed_imageContainer_figure"><img src="http://www.trbimg.com/img-53e8dc49/turbine/lat-buzzfeed-la0011761750-20131007/750/16x9" data-height="450" data-width="750" data-ratio="16x9" itemprop="image" data-baseurl="http://www.trbimg.com/img-53e8dc49/turbine/lat-buzzfeed-la0011761750-20131007" alt="Buzzfeed" class="trb_embed_imageContainer_img" title="Buzzfeed" data-content-naturalwidth="2048" data-content-naturalheight="1365"></figure><div class="trb_embed_related" data-role="lightbox_metadata">      <span class="trb_embed_related_title">Buzzfeed</span>  <div class="trb_embed_related_credit">Jay L. Clendenin / Los Angeles Times</div>  <div class="trb_embed_related_caption">Buzzfeed's Los Angeles headquarters on Beverly Boulevard on Oct. 7, 2013.</div>  <div class="trb_embed_related_credit_and_caption">Buzzfeed's Los Angeles headquarters on Beverly Boulevard on Oct. 7, 2013. (Jay L. Clendenin / Los Angeles Times)</div></div>    </div>
```

The code that I am running is:

```
image_section = soup.find(class_ = "trb_embed_media")
print image_section
print "================="
img = image_section.find('img')['src']
print img
```

The output of line 2 of the code above is:

```
<div class="trb_embed_media ">
<figure class="trb_embed_imageContainer_figure" data-role=" delayload  delayload_done imgsize_item">
<img alt="Buzzfeed" class="trb_embed_imageContainer_img" data-baseurl="http://www.trbimg.com/img-53e8dc49/turbine/lat-buzzfeed-la0011761750-20131007" data-content-naturalheight="1365" data-content-naturalwidth="2048" itemprop="image" title="Buzzfeed"/>
</figure>
<div class="trb_embed_related" data-role="lightbox_metadata">
<span class="trb_embed_related_title">
         Buzzfeed
</span>
<div class="trb_embed_related_credit">
         Jay L. Clendenin / Los Angeles Times
</div>
<div class="trb_embed_related_caption">
         Buzzfeed's Los Angeles headquarters on Beverly Boulevard on Oct. 7, 2013.
</div>
<div class="trb_embed_related_credit_and_caption">
         Buzzfeed's Los Angeles headquarters on Beverly Boulevard on Oct. 7, 2013. (Jay L. Clendenin / Los Angeles Times)
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

As you can see from the img tag above. It is missing the src attribute, even through it is present in the original HTML source. What am I missing here. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the *original HTML source* **doesn't** contain the `src` attribute, Javascript adds that attribute *after the page is loaded*.

The javascript code presumably uses the `data-baseurl` attribute to generate the `src` URL, adding a size and ratio.

The `delayload` and `imgsize_item` values in the `data-role` attribute on the parent `<figure>` tag is a hint there too. You'll have to calculate your own aspect ratio from the given `data-content-naturalheight` and `data-content-naturalwidth` attributes and go from there.

If you resize the page you'll see that the site is using a responsive design; different image sizes are loaded based on how much horizontal space is available.

A quick experiment shows that you can fill in *any* size in the URL, as well as any aspect ratio, and the image is *autogenerated* based on those.

If you wanted to get the full size image, all you have to do is load the base URL; it returns the un-scaled image.

The [javascript used to generate size and ratio](http://www.trbas.com/jive/prod/common/javascripts/main.1q2w3_59f91aea965ee275f98d2e98156c2b78.js) picks among `16x9`, `1x1` and `9x16` aspect ratios, based on the ratio between height and width from the data attributes:

```
img = soup.select('div.trb_embed_media img')[0]
width, height = map(int, (img['data-content-naturalwidth'], img['data-content-naturalheight']))
ratio = width / float(height)
ratio = '1x1' if 0.9 <= ratio <= 1.1 else '16x9' if ratio > 1.1 else '9x16'
img_url = '{}/{}/{}'.format(img['data-baseurl'], width, ratio)
```

For your example that generates http://www.trbimg.com/img-53e8dc49/turbine/lat-buzzfeed-la0011761750-20131007/2048/16x9, a valid image:

```
>>> import requests
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> r = requests.get('http://www.latimes.com/business/la-fi-tn-buzzfeed-deal-20140811-story.html')
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
>>> img = soup.select('div.trb_embed_media img')[0]
>>> width, height = map(int, (img['data-content-naturalwidth'], img['data-content-naturalheight']))
>>> ratio = width / float(height)
>>> ratio = '1x1' if 0.9 <= ratio <= 1.1 else '16x9' if ratio > 1.1 else '9x16'
>>> '{}/{}/{}'.format(img['data-baseurl'], width, ratio)
'http://www.trbimg.com/img-53e8dc49/turbine/lat-buzzfeed-la0011761750-20131007/2048/16x9'
```

Comment: Ok I get it. So what you saying is that it cannot be extracted. Instead it needs to be constructed, correct? There is still something bothering me about your solution in that although it works it should still be possible to extract the src attribute after it has been constructed in my web browser.

Comment: @ImranNazir: you'd have to either use a different solution to execute the JavaScript after loading all resources, or reverse-engineer the JavaScript code and re-implement that in Python. You can use Selenium or some headless-browser library to do the former.

Comment: @ImranNazir: note that the whole width/height and ratio dance are not even needed; the base URL gives you the full-size image without scaling and cropping.